# Functions of jdbc Driver

Tags: java, database, jdbc, odbc

Why jdbc odbc driver written as jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver or sun.jadbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc Driver?
In which file the name is stored?
 eg.

```
 Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")
```

And  What are the functions of jdbcodbc driver and odbc driver?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver

Comment: All excellent questions to google!

Answer (score 1):

> Why jdbc odbc driver written as jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver or sun.jadbc.odbc.JdbcOdbc Driver?

Because (presumably) there are two different JDBC->ODBC driver classes, and those are their respective fully qualified class names.  (Your question is a bit like asking *"why are tyres called Michelin and Goodyear?"*)

> In which file the name is stored?

That entirely depends on the design of your application and/or the framework it is using for persistence.

> eg.  `Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver")`

In that example, the class name is hard-wired into the source code.  Why?  You'd need to ask the person who wrote it!!

> And What are the functions of jdbcodbc driver and odbc driver?

A plain ODBC driver provides client-side ODBC APIs that an application can use to make calls to a database.  The driver implements that functionality by interfacing with the vendor-specific native database protocols and / or APIs.  Thus, the driver is *hiding* the database-specific stuff behind a database independent *facade*.

A plain JDBC driver does the same thing *except* that it is providing JDBC APIs.

A JDBC-ODBC driver is actually a "bridge" between the JDBC and ODBC APIs.  The application makes JDBC calls that are mapped to ODBC class by the driver.  This driver then calls a plain ODBC driver which talks to the actual database.  (You would use this if you had a database that had only ODBC drivers, and you wanted to access it from an application implemented to use JDBC.)

For more information on JDBC and ODBC, refer to the respective Wikipedia pages, etcetera.

Answer (score 0):

When you use Class.forName(), you create a new class with the given fully qualified name. Since you connect to a DB, you must use the DB driver specific to the type of connection you use. After that I assume you will use DriverManager to create a connection to that resource. The DriverManager will look for classes that can use the connection string you pass to it.